# How can I add child nodes to child nodes in mindmaps?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, mindmaps

I would like to organize the following mind mapping by:

- Formatting it
- Add children "level 1-2-1, Level 1-2-3, Level 1-2-3 " to node level 1-2

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
{\centering
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [mindmap,
      grow cyclic,
      every node/.style=concept,
      concept color=teal!40,
      level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/7},
      level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5},
      ]
      \node [root concept] {Leve 0}
        child [concept color=purple!40]{
          node    {Level 1}
          child { node    {Level 1-1} }
          child { node    {Level 1-2} }
          child { node    {Level 1-3} }
          child { node    {Level 1-4} }
        }
        child [concept color=pink!40, rotate=-10]{
          node     {Level 2}
          child { node    {Level 2-1} }
          child { node    {Level 2-2} }
                     child { node    {Level 2-2} }
                     child { node    {Level 2-3} }
        }
        child [concept color=green!40, rotate=-20]{
          node  {Level 3}
          child { node {Level 3-1} }
          child { node {Level 3-2} }
          child { node {Level 3-3} }
          child { node {Level 3-4} }
        }
        child [concept color=red!40, rotate=-10]{
          node  {Level 4}[counterclockwise from=-115]
          child  { node {Level 4-1} }
          child { node {Level 4-2} }
          child { node {Level 4-3} }
          child { node {Level 4-4} }
          child { node {Feeding practices} }
        }
        child [concept color=blue!40, rotate=-7.5]{
          node     {Level 5}
          child { node {Level 5-1} }
          child { node {Level 5-2} }
          child { node {Level 5-3} }
          child { node {Level 5-4} }
          child { node {Level 5-5} }
          child { node {Level 5-6} }
        }
        child [concept color=yellow!40, rotate=-5]{
          node   {Level 6}%[clockwise from=45, level distance=8cm]
         child { node {Level 6-3} }
        } 
      ;
  \end{tikzpicture}}\par}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added these nodes and also cured the overlaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
{\centering
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [mindmap,
      grow cyclic,
      every node/.style=concept,
      concept color=teal!40,
      level 1/.append style={sibling angle=360/7},
      level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5},
      ]
      \node [root concept] {Level 0}
        child [concept color=purple!40]{
          node    {Level 1}
          child { node    {Level 1-1} }
          child { node    {Level 1-2} 
            child {node {Level 1-2-1}}
            child {node {Level 1-2-2}}
            child {node {Level 1-2-3}}}
          child { node    {Level 1-3} }
          child { node    {Level 1-4} }
        }
        child [concept color=pink!40, rotate=10]{
          node     {Level 2}
          child { node    {Level 2-1} }
          child { node    {Level 2-2} }
                     child { node    {Level 2-2} }
                     child { node    {Level 2-3} }
        }
        child [concept color=green!40, rotate=20]{
          node  {Level 3}
          child { node {Level 3-1} }
          child { node {Level 3-2} }
          child { node {Level 3-3} }
          child { node {Level 3-4} }
        }
        child [concept color=red!40, rotate=30]{
          node  {Level 4}[counterclockwise from=-115]
          child  { node {Level 4-1} }
          child { node {Level 4-2} }
          child { node {Level 4-3} }
          child { node {Level 4-4} }
          child { node {Feeding practices} }
        }
        child [concept color=blue!40, rotate=40]{
          node     {Level 5}
          child { node {Level 5-1} }
          child { node {Level 5-2} }
          child { node {Level 5-3} }
          child { node {Level 5-4} }
          child { node {Level 5-5} }
          child { node {Level 5-6} }
        }
        child [concept color=yellow!40, rotate=45]{
          node   {Level 6}%[clockwise from=45, level distance=8cm]
         child { node {Level 6-3} }
        } 
      ;
  \end{tikzpicture}}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]